# I need to connect two layout activity and to get them in one layout activity with borders?

Tags: android

I need help to connect two layout activity and to get both of them in one layout as output,also each one with borders? please help me to find these...

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your two activities into [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), and put them both in one activity.